# Java Spring-MVC application doesn't send CSS and JS files. Error 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resources

Problem is common, I've tried a lot of solutions but nothing works for me.
I am quite new in Spring so I may not understand some things.

I've got next files structure:

[image: Files structure of project]

My link inside page is templated by Thymeleaf like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}" type="text/css"/>
```

Also, there is  attribute in head of html.

Ok, and my spring-context.xml is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <!--to pick up all annotation in the package-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="langquiz"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>
</beans>
```

I've tried some manipulations with mapping (like writing location="/templates/css/" or location="css/"), also tried resource handler in configuration class.  But nothing helps.

Thank you!

**UPD:**
Changed

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>
```

to

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/templates/"/>
```

and also tried

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/"/>
```

but still have no result.

Comment: So you're not using Spring Boot?

Comment: @chrylis yes, it's Spring-MVC + ThymeLeaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/templates/css/"/>
```

Or adding a resource handler,

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/templates/css/");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping is incorrect in which `location` should include your `templates` directory as well as shown below:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/templates/css/"/>
```

You can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) from the spring doc on this:

> For example, to serve resource requests with a URL pattern of
>   **/resources/** from a **public-resources** directory within the web
>   application root you would use:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/"/>
```

Comment: what else can I be missing?

Comment: Is there ability to check where resources are tried to e taken?

Answer (score 0):

Changed  to  to make it work.

Still wondering if there is a way to see web site not on http://localhost:8080/project-name-snapshot but on http://localhost:8080

Comment: Deploy your project as ROOT, that is the easiest

Comment: @SAP is there a way to do it with GlassFish?